# Error al ejecutar trigger after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Trigger :

> INSERT INTO pagos SET identrada = NEW.id,idusuario = NEW.idusuario,
>   idcuenta = NEW.idcuenta,pago = 0, descripcion = 'Entrada', sinpagar =
>   0, forma = 'S/P',hora = NEW.hora,fecha=NEW.fecha,posfecha=NEW.fecha

Mi tabla entrada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla pagos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi error :

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`munici27_proHASS`.`pagos`, CONSTRAINT `pagos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`identrada`) REFERENCES `entrada` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Verifica esta linea  identrada = NEW.id ya que NEW.id aun no existe como registro en la tabla entrada, para hacer referencia a una clave foranea de una tabla el registro debe existir, de ser esa la respuesta se vale +1.

Comment: pero se supone que es después de ver insertado el _id_ por eso el after simplemente estoy pasando ese que se creo.

Comment: El problema es que le estas diciendo al motor de base de datos que quieres insertar una referencia de un registro de una tabla que todavia no existe, la entrada debe existir primero que el pago.